# php json output to chartkick linechart format

Tags: javascript, json, chartkick

I have a php json response coming to js via ajax call and the json response is as below

```
{
 "success":true,
 "dataset":[{"COUNTITEMS":41,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-27 00:00:00 -2359"},
   {"COUNTITEMS":68,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-28 00:00:00 -2359"},
   {"COUNTITEMS":63,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-29 00:00:00 -2359"},
   {"COUNTITEMS":327,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-30 00:00:00 -2359"},
   {"COUNTITEMS":46,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-31 00:00:00 -2359"}]
}
```

chartkick.js requires the following format. In my js file, this is how it works if I hard coded.

```
    var view_dates =        {
            "2015-10-27 00:00:00 -2359":41,
            "2015-10-28 00:00:00 -2359":68,
            "2015-10-29 00:00:00 -2359":63,
            "2015-10-30 00:00:00 -2359":327,
            "2015-10-31 00:00:00 -2359":46
            };
   new Chartkick.LineChart("chart-1", view_dates);
```

I cannot parse the json response to how chart kick requires. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e7mmyd0k/) (You have to see result in console=> by inspect element)

You can assign and initiate any new property for a json object with any value;

```
var newObject = {};
newObject[propertyNameOfYourChoice_Means_NewName] = propertyValue;
```

This was solution to your problem. Now you could see how its implmented

```
 var g = {
     "success":true,
     "dataset":[{"COUNTITEMS":41,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-27 00:00:00 -2359"},
       {"COUNTITEMS":68,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-28 00:00:00 -2359"},
       {"COUNTITEMS":63,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-29 00:00:00 -2359"},
       {"COUNTITEMS":327,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-30 00:00:00 -2359"},
       {"COUNTITEMS":46,"VIEW_DATE":"2015-10-31 00:00:00 -2359"}]
    };

parseJSONForChartkick(g);

function parseJSONForChartkick(oldObject)
{
var newObject = {};
var propertyName;
var propertyValue;
var ar = oldObject.dataset;
for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
{
propertyName = ar[i].VIEW_DATE; //You might need not following
propertyName = '"'+ar[i].VIEW_DATE+'"'; //Use This or above line
propertyValue = ar[i].COUNTITEMS;
newObject[propertyName] = propertyValue;
}
console.log(newObject);

}
```